# what is the best approach for integrating on-premises linux Jenkins to Github enterprise?

Tags: jenkins, github-enterprise

what is the best approach for integrating on-premises linux Jenkins to Github enterprise?

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use [jenkins github plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/solutions/github/) or just use git.
Create a Jenkins job with gitgub repo and create a hook in Github do start Jenkins jobs.